gray framed box around text and math in springer book style
I am looking for a library in latex that allows me to create a gray box, like the one seen in a springer book, to describe definitions and theorems


Doesn't look different. It's differnt, but thanks for your try

Then please edit your question to make clear how it's different and add some code that shows what you've tried.
